# How can I add or edit chapter markers with an m4v file?

Tags: video, video-editor

I am doing some simple video editing and I want to add/edit chapters.  This is a 5 hour video, so chapter makers can be very useful.  I ripped video from DVDs using handbrake and put them together using OpenShot.  Handbrake preserved the chapters from the DVD, but I want to create my own chapter markers.  OpenShot has removed all chapter markers and I don't see a way of adding them.

Answer (score 1):

click the chapters tab in handbrake. turn the check mark on for chapters. and then write your own chapter names and times in the timetable.